# Bootstrap Dropdown menu troubleshoot

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, drop-down-menu

I am building a site here:

[Website Link](http://apaaportugal.doidosou.eu/)

The drop-down navbar menu is working fine except the fact that when there is a mouse-over on the items to the right of the navbar, the first drop-down menu activates. (i.e. Click on Administration and both its drop-down menu and the drop-down menu under "who are we" also drops down!)

Any further suggestions, please?

The code is as follows:

```
  <nav id="myNav"  class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-top" role="navigation"> 
    <div class="container dropdown">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header dropdown">
```

-->
                
                    Toggle navigation

```
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dropdown" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-hover="dropdown">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right dropdown">
                <li>
                            <a href="index.php">_Home</a>
                        </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="who_are_we.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">_Who are we?<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="who_are_we.php#abouttheassociation">_About the Association</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="who_are_we.php#objectives">_Objectives</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dt_bg">
                            <a href="who_are_we.php#quemsomos">_Quem Somos?</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="how_do_we_help.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">_How do we help?<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="how_do_we_help.php#snips">_Snips</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="udder.php">_Other</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dt_bg">
                            <a href="forms.php">_Forms</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="how_can_you_help.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">_How can <strong>You</strong> help?<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                                <a href="how_can_you_help.php#ourshops" class="trigger right-caret">_Our Shops</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                            <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                                        <a href="how_can_you_help.php#alvor">_Alvor</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="how_can_you_help.php#albufeira">_Albufeira</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dt_bg">
                                        <a href="how_can_you_help.php#silves">_Silves</a>
                                    </li>
                        </ul>


                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="how_can_you_help.php#fundraising">_Fundraising</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dt_bg">
                            <a href="how_can_you_help.php#membership">_Membership</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="latest_news.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">_Latest News<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="latest_news.php#events">_Upcoming Events</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="latest_news.php#other">_Other</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="structure.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">_Administration<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="structure.php#thestructure" class="trigger right-caret">_Structure of the association</a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                            <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                                        <a href="structure.php#managementboard">_Management Board</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="structure.php#fiscalcouncil">_Fiscal Council</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dt_bg">
                                        <a href="structure.php#membership">_Annual General Assembly</a>
                                    </li>
                        </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="structure.php#annualreports">_Reports & Accounts</a>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </li>
             <li>
                    <a href="apaa_vet_links.php">_Vet Clinics</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.php">_Contact</a>
                </li>  

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
```

Any help in seeing where the problem is would be gratefully received as my eyes are going after hours of tring nto find the problem.

Many Thanks

Update:

I have applied the solution proposed by @Spade but the situation remains.

Using [link]http://apaaportugal.doidosou.eu/useful_links.php as a test page (no carousel) onmouseover on any dropdown menu item also activates the first drop-down under item "_who are we".

Javascript code on the page is:

```
       <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Sub-Menu JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/sub_menu.js"></script>

<!-- header script -->
    <script>

        var headerHeight = 200;

        $(window).bind('scroll', function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > headerHeight) {
            $('#myNav').removeClass('navbar-top');
            $('#myNav').addClass('navbar-fixed-top');
        } else {
            $('#myNav').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top');
            $('#myNav').addClass('navbar-top');
        }
        });

</script>
<!-- Bootstrap Dropdown Hover JS -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap-dropdownhover.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function() {
    $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();

    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();

    });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(this).width();

    if (width < 769) {
      $('.navbar .dropdown').removeClass('test');
    } else {
      $('.navbar .dropdown').addClass('test');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Navbar Html code as follows:

```
    <!-- Header Content -->
    <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
        <a href="index.php" class="pull-left"><img src="/images/APPA_logo_R_80.png"></a><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-11">
                <div>
                    <h1 class="h_header">APAA - Association for the Protection of Animals in the Algarve</h1>
                    <h3 class="h_header">Associação de Protecção Animal do Algarve</h3>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>



    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav id="myNav"  class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-top" role="navigation"> 
        <div class="container dropdown">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header dropdown">
<!--                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">-->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

    </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse dropdown" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-hover="dropdown">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right dropdown">
                <li>
                            <a href="index.php">_Home</a>
                        </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="who_are_we.php" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled">_Who are we?<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="who_are_we.php#abouttheassociation">_About the Association</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="who_are_we.php#objectives">_Objectives</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dt_bg">
                            <a href="who_are_we.php#quemsomos">_Quem Somos?</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="how_do_we_help.php" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled">_How do we help?<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="how_do_we_help.php#snips">_Snips</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="how_do_we_help.php#other">_Other</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dt_bg">
                            <a href="how_do_we_help.php#forms">_Forms</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="how_can_you_help.php" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled">_How can <strong>You</strong> help?<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                                <a href="how_can_you_help.php#ourshops" class="trigger right-caret">_Our Shops</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                            <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                                        <a href="how_can_you_help.php#alvor">_Alvor</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="how_can_you_help.php#albufeira">_Albufeira</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dt_bg">
                                        <a href="how_can_you_help.php#silves">_Silves</a>
                                    </li>
                        </ul>


                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="how_can_you_help.php#fundraising">_Fundraising</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dt_bg">
                            <a href="how_can_you_help.php#membership">_Membership</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="latest_news.php" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled">_Latest News<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="latest_news.php#events">_Upcoming Events</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="latest_news.php#other">_Other</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="structure.php" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled">_Administration<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="structure.php#thestructure" class="trigger right-caret">_Structure of the association</a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                            <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                                        <a href="structure.php#managementboard">_Management Board</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="structure.php#fiscalcouncil">_Fiscal Council</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dt_bg">
                                        <a href="structure.php#membership">_Annual General Assembly</a>
                                    </li>
                        </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="structure.php#annualreports">_Reports & Accounts</a>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="useful_links.php" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle disabled">_Useful Links<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                                <a href="apaa_vet_links.php">_Algarve - Veterinary Surgeries</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="other_agencies.php">_Algarve - Other animal-related institutions</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.php">_Contact</a>
                </li>  

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Comment: post javascript also

Comment: Have just posted an update with code

Answer (score 2):

Two things need to be changed:

1) Replace "Script to Activate the Carousel" with the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();

    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();

    });

  $(window).resize(function() {
    var width = $(this).width();

    if (width < 769) {
      $('.navbar .dropdown').removeClass('test');
    } else {
      $('.navbar .dropdown').addClass('test');
    }
  });
});
```

2) Replace the code you shared for Navigation with the following:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav id="myNav"  class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-top" role="navigation"> 
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                            <a href="index.php">_Home</a>
                        </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="who_are_we.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">_Who are we?<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="who_are_we.php#abouttheassociation">_About the Association</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="">
                            <a href="who_are_we.php#objectives">_Objectives</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dt_bg">
                            <a href="who_are_we.php#quemsomos">_Quem Somos?</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="how_do_we_help.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">_How do we help?<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="how_do_we_help.php#snips">_Snips</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="udder.php">_Other</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dt_bg">
                            <a href="forms.php">_Forms</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="how_can_you_help.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">_How can <strong>You</strong> help?<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                                <a href="how_can_you_help.php#ourshops" class="trigger right-caret">_Our Shops</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                            <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                                        <a href="how_can_you_help.php#alvor">_Alvor</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="how_can_you_help.php#albufeira">_Albufeira</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dt_bg">
                                        <a href="how_can_you_help.php#silves">_Silves</a>
                                    </li>
                        </ul>


                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="how_can_you_help.php#fundraising">_Fundraising</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dt_bg">
                            <a href="how_can_you_help.php#membership">_Membership</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>
                </li>
                 <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="latest_news.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">_Latest News<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="latest_news.php#events">_Upcoming Events</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="latest_news.php#other">_Other</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="structure.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">_Administration<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="structure.php#thestructure" class="trigger right-caret">_Structure of the association</a>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
                            <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                                        <a href="structure.php#managementboard">_Management Board</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="structure.php#fiscalcouncil">_Fiscal Council</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="dt_bg">
                                        <a href="structure.php#membership">_Annual General Assembly</a>
                                    </li>
                        </ul>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="structure.php#annualreports">_Reports & Accounts</a>
                        </li>


                    </ul>
                </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="useful_links.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">_Useful Links<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="dt_bg dropdown">
                            <a href="apaa_vet_links.php">_Algarve - Veterinary Surgeries</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="other_agencies.php">_Algarve - Other animal-related institutions</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>

                                <li>
                    <a href="contact.php">_Contact</a>
                </li>  

            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Also Attaching the result at my side:

[image]

Comment: I have applied these solutions but the situation remains.

Comment: @cgkh Please Replace Navigation Code which I shared. You are still using your code for navigation, I have changed some class names, which will help to solve your problem. You have only updated java-script code.  You can see in the attached image its working at my side.